# Valid XML or not (encoded characters)?

Tags: xml, validation, encoding

I have the following xml snippet which gets sent to an external web service (note the line feeds):

```
<xml>
<address>Bob Jones
100 Main St.
Smallville Ohio 39391</address>
</xml>
```

The web service responds with:

```
<xml>
<address>Bob Jones&#10;100 Main St.&#10;Smallville Ohio 39391</address>
</xml>
```

In essence the service seems to be encoding line feeds with an html encoding? The only xml encoded values I've seen are:

```
&lt;
&gt;
&quot;
&amp;
&apos;
```

or have the following format to represent unicode characters (where u is a digit)

```
&#uuuu;
```

The only encoding i've found online that uses `&#10;` seems to be html encoding. Is this also a valid xml encoding? I thought from the format above it would have to have 4 digits. Online xml checkers are telling me it's valid xml which is surprising me. If this is valid xml, is it bad practice to encode a completely valid xml character (line feed) for seemingly no reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

&#10; is always valid in XML, and a normal parser will simply replace it with the character. &#ANY_16_bit_number; is in fact also valid. You can specify any Unicode character.